# GridBagLayout dividing JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, gridbaglayout

i am trying to divide my JPanel using GBL on 200 rows and 200 columns(one cell for one pixel. Any idea how to do this properly. Code posted below doesn't work for me.

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel;
pane.setSize(200,200);
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
layout.columnWidths = new int[200];     layout.rowHeights = new int[200];
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) class to set the size of each pixel using the `gridwidth` and `gridheight` properties. Then apply these constraints to your GBL using `layout.setConstraints(GridBagConstraints instance)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do, you would just need to add the part to change the pixels by either reading a list or array:

```
int y=0;
int x=0;
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

for(int stop=0;stop<=200;stop++){
c.gridx = ++x;
c.gridy = ++y;
pane.add(each_pixel, c);
 }
```